# How to create a custom video Control option in embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, video, website, google-api

I am trying to embed Youtube videos on my website with a customized control option like in Edx. [image: Screenshot of embedded YouTube videos on Edx] 
However, I didn't find any proper documentation to achieve this. I tried to look at the [YouTube Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls). 
Can you please advise me how to achieve this or any tutorial/documentation link?

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation you linked, there is a "[Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)" section with some sample code. Using this sample code, as well as a quick look at the documentation, I found that a simple `<button onClick"=player.playVideo()">`gives you a button to play the video again (as the sample code will auto-stop the video 6s in)

You can see the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/LEOXD/eLqk2sxc/

The Getting Started section also includes sample code for just [loading the player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)

From here, you basically only need to design your own little bar underneath the player. (it doesn't have to be `<button>`s).

Note that YouTube doesn't count views coming from custom players.